# How to get the values of the same column aganist the distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the summary for one column in sql.
The below is the code but i am unable to achieve my output. I Want the count of account number Beside the distinct account number column.

```
Select distinct (Account_number), count(Distinct Account_number) As number_of_acc
From txn
Group by Account_number
```

The output should be like:

```
Account_number number_of_acc
Xx1.               2
Xx3.               1
Xx6.               4
```

Since the account number repeats as per the counts mentioned in the column number_of_acc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just apply the group by clause on the account number

select Account_number,count(1) as  number_of_acc
from txn
group by Account_number

Answer (score 2):

Remove the **DISTINCT** keyword from the query since it is already taken care by **GROUP BY** statement.

```
SELECT Account_number, COUNT(Account_number) AS number_of_acc
FROM txn
GROUP BY Account_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROW NUMBER`

```
SELECT S.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,COUNT(*) FROM(
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER ORDER BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER) AS RW
FROM TXN) S
WHERE S.RW=1
GROUP BY S.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
```